# MySQL Multiple Columns vs Single Column for speed/optimization

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, structure

I'm working on a database that describes different physical characteristics of certain people.

My question is, would performance be quicker/less of a workload to have multiple columns setup like so:

```
HAIR | EYES | HEIGHT | WEIGHT
brwn | blue | 5'9"   | 150
```

Or have a single column separating the data with delimiter, like so:

```
ATTRIBUTES
Hair: Brown,
Eyes: Blue,
Height: 5'9",
Weight: 150
```

Does one have an edge of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have separate columns for each attribute. Otherwise why are you even using a database?

Comment: +1: Trying to get specifics, like the number of people with blue eyes would be incredibly painful

Answer (score 1):

The performance difference would be minimal, if any. The problem with delimiting the data in a single column is that it makes it more difficult and resource intensive to perform a search. What if you want to find all people that weight between 150 and 160 and have blonde hair? Wont be that easy with it all stuffed in a single column.

Comment: Impact depends on the operation